# Why can't the style I have within a control template use templatebinding?

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate

I have this control template that I am writing:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:InfoBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:InfoBar}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding LeftInfoBarTextBlockCollection}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding MiddleInfoBarTextBlockCollection}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding RightInfoBarTextBlockCollection}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This section of xaml is throwing `member is not valid because it does not contain a valid type name.` exceptions for the template bindings on FontFamily, FontSize and Foreground.

```
<Grid.Resources>
```

If I change it to this:

```
 <Grid.Resources>
```

It will build, but when I debug it, I get this `XmlParseExeption`:

`Set property 'System.Windows.Setter.Value' threw an exception.`

If I change `controls:InfoBar` to `Control`, which InfoBar inherits from, I get the same exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">         
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" />         
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />         
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />         
</Style>
```

You can use ***TemplateBinding*** only inside a control template.
and here you using it inside a style.

Comment: Is there any way I can accomplish what I was trying to do in that style, without the TemplateBinding?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, Justin, you can create a style that applies a control template.

Notice that this style assigns a control template to the the Template property of a pushpin when the pushpin style is set to NumberPushpinStyle.

```
<Style x:Key="NumberPushpinStyle" TargetType="m:Pushpin">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFF4F4F5" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Ellipse Fill="Black" Height="33" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" Width="33" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
              <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-16" TranslateY="16" />
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
          </Ellipse>
          <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
              <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-16" TranslateY="15" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```